# Get hour without space %time:~0,2%

Tags: datetime, batch-file, cmd, datetime-format, timestamping

I am giving files names that includes their creation dates.

I have done it like this so far:
    filename%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.txt

It seemed to work fine when i tested it, but now i discovered that my script fails when it is run between 12:00AM and 10:00AM.

I just located the reason:

```
  A:\Archive>echo %date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%
20170217 93258
```

For some reason when the hour is only one digit, a space occur.

Is there any way to fix this?

Its a .bat script btw :)

Comment: Store your date/time string in a variable, say `datetime`, then do `%datetime: =0%`...

Comment: I solved it like this:
'code' if "%time:~0,1%" == " " (set dtstamp=0%time:~1,1%) ELSE set dtstamp=%time:~0,2% 'code'

Comment: Use WMIC to get the date and time.